# Why await-import inside a function instead of top level import?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-modules, dynamic-import

In a large code base, there are await import statements like this

```
const { "default": MenuView } = await import('./menu/MenuView');
const { "default": MenuViewModel } = await import('./menu/MenuViewModel');
```

Here's a larger context:

```
import { View } from 'backbone.marionette';
import RivetsBehavior from 'behaviors/RivetsBehavior';
import tpl from './Mask.HeaderView.html';
import './Mask.HeaderView.scss';


export default View.extend({
  behaviors: [RivetsBehavior],
  template: tpl,

  regions: {
    menu: ".mask-menu"
  },

  async onRender() {
    const { "default": MenuView } = await import('./menu/MenuView'); // <---------------
    const { "default": MenuViewModel } = await import('./menu/MenuViewModel'); // <-----

    const oMenuViewModel = new MenuViewModel();
    oMenuViewModel.setOptions(this.options);

    this.showChildView('menu', new MenuView({
        model: oMenuViewModel
    }));
  }
});
```

I moved the imports to the top of the file:

```
import { View } from 'backbone.marionette';
import RivetsBehavior from 'behaviors/RivetsBehavior';
import tpl from './mask.HeaderView.html';
import './mask.HeaderView.scss';
import MenuView from './menu/MenuView'; // <---------------------------- here
import MenuViewModel from './menu/MenuViewModel'; // <------------------- here


export default View.extend({
  behaviors: [RivetsBehavior],
  template: tpl,

  regions: {
    menu: ".maskn-menu"
  },

  async onRender() {
    // const { "default": MenuView } = await import('./menu/MenuView'); <------------ no
    // const { "default": MenuViewModel } = await import('./menu/MenuViewModel'); <-- no

    const oMenuViewModel = new MenuViewModel();
    oMenuViewModel.setOptions(this.options);

    this.showChildView('menu', new MenuView({
        model: oMenuViewModel
    }));
  }
});
```

Everything seems to work. But I am worried that I am missing something.

**Questions**

1. Why not simply place those await imports with the other imports at the top of the file?
2. Could this be performance related? In the example there are only 2 await-imports but the code base has e.g. one file with 60 functions and in each function there are 2 await-imports. Each function imports something different.
3. Could this be UI experience related (i.e. avoid blocking the UI).

Answer (score 2):

Everything should work fine with static `import`s as well. Both codes should work.

But when you import those modules dynamically, it can be a bit better in this case:

The modules get imported statically, they will be executed before executing the module that imported them. Opposed to that, when the import is in the `onRender` function, the imported modules are evaluated first time the function is called.

That way, we can defer the execution of the imported modules until they are really needed. If `onRender` is never called, these modules aren't get imported at all.

So, although your version will work as well, the original can be a bit better (but it also depends on the way how the `onRender` function is called).